# WSO2 bam - to many open cursors running Hive script

Tags: hive, wso2, wso2-bam

I have been running wso2 bam 2.0.1 for some time now without any problem, but within the latest days I see errors : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded running the same script.

At the moment there is about 140000 rows in Cassandra. The Oracle db has max_open_cursors set to 3000.

I'm running with the default configuration, but are updating correlated data in some Oracle tables using a Hive script similar to the Service_Statistics_Monitoring toolbox.

Is there any way to control how many cursors gets used, or are the any other way to control this ?

Error from log ->

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-19 16:38:28,247] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation} -  Failed to write data to database {org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation}java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3368)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation.updateData(DBOperation.java:115)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation.writeToDB(DBOperation.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBRecordWriter.write(DBRecordWriter.java:35)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processAggr(GroupByOperator.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processOp(GroupByOperator.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:256)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2012-11-19 16:38:28,259] FATAL {ExecReducer} -  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) {"key":{"_col0":"rds-program-nownext","_col1":2012,"_col2":11,"_col3":6,"_col4":2,"_col5":"2012-11-06 02"},"value":{"_col0":18,"_col1":{"count":18,"sum":21541.0},"_col2":1184,"_col3":1205,"_col4":21541},"alias":0}
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:518)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:256)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processOp(GroupByOperator.java:737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:247)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBOperation.writeToDB(DBOperation.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storage.db.DBRecordWriter.write(DBRecordWriter.java:35)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FileSinkOperator.processOp(FileSinkOperator.java:589)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator.processOp(SelectOperator.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.process(Operator.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.forward(Operator.java:762)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.forward(GroupByOperator.java:959)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processAggr(GroupByOperator.java:798)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processOp(GroupByOperator.java:724)
    ... 5 more
 {ExecReducer} e(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:599)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:536)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:966)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:643)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:637)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(template_jsp.java:539)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:290)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:477)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:258)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.handleRequest(ServletRegistration.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:172)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting the issue. We have fixed it for BAM 2.0.2[1], So this fix will be available in next BAM release.

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BAM-993

Thanks,
Kasun.